# Laravel - paginated model sort link in blade view

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

In laravel 5.2 I have a paginated table of a model.

@CityController

```
public function index(Request $request){
        $cities = City::orderBy('name');
        return view('pages.city.index', ["cities" => $cities ->paginate(25)]);
    }
```

This works fine, but when I try to sort the results inside the blade view does not work.

@index.blade.php

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="sui-columnheader">
      <th class="sui-headercell" data-field="Id">
        <a href="{!! $cities->appends(['sort' => 'id'])->links() !!}">Id</a>
      </th>
 </thead>
 <tbody class="list">
    @foreach ($cities as $city)
    <tr class="sui-row">
      <td class="sui-cell id">{!! $city->id !!}</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

When I click the sort button just reloads the page but no sort is applied.

Is because of the "orderBy" clause?
How can I make it work and defaults to order by name?
Am I missing something?

Comment: Try do add "asc" or "desc" order, for example like this $cities = City::orderBy('name', 'asc');

Comment: @Diego182 No change.

Comment: try to change ->links() TO ->render()  - https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination

Comment: You can try also to paginate cities before of pass to view. Maybe so it will work: $cities = City::orderBy('name')->paginate(25);
  
  return view('pages.city.index', ["cities" => $cities ]);

Comment: Unfortunately any of these solutions work for me.

Comment: What does your city table or migration look like? Can you add `$city->name` in the foreach loop instead of just the ID to double check that it is indeed not sorting?

Comment: The table have id and name. Is not sorting.

Comment: The query is orderBy 'name', unless you change that you will keep getting the same result. All appends does is add query string params to the url, you will need to check for those in the controller and do what you need based upon them to change that query.

Comment: And how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this perhaps. You would want to make sure you limit what can be passed to that `orderBy`. A URL like "`...something?sort=blah`" would cause `orderBy('blah')`, which your table doesn't have, which will cause a DB error.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $cities = City::orderBy($request->input('sort', 'name'))->paginate(25);
    return view('pages.city.index', ['cities' => $cities]);
}

{{ $cities->appends(Request::query())->render() }}
```

Just giving you a functional example, though you will have to adjust based on your own rules.

The `appends` is just allowing you to continue to paginate based on the current sorting, by passing the sort option via the query string of the pagination links.

**Update:**

Using your example where there is a default, but imagining there can be more than just 1 other field to sort by:

```
$sort = trim($request->input('sort'));
// if it is in the acceptable array use it, otherwise default to 'name'
$sort = in_array($sort, ['id', ...]) ? $sort : 'name';
$cities = City::orderBy($sort)->paginate(25);

<table>
    <tr>
        <th><a href="{{ Request::fullUrlWithQuery(['sort' => 'id']) }}">ID</a></th>
        <th><a href="{{ Request::url() }}">NAME</a></th>
        ...
    </tr>
    @foreach ($cities as $city)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $city->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $city->name }}</td>
        ...
    </tr>
    @endforeach
...
{{ $cities->appends(Request::query())->render() }}
```

Just an example, you can do this how you would like.

Comment: I just realize the url is not changing when I click the sort link. Should it change?

Comment: <a href="{!! $cities->appends(['sort' => 'id'])->links() !!}">Id</a>

Comment: you should have separate links to start the sorting as those are the pagination links that will append what currently is being used ... check the updated version